# How to implement child-parent aggregation link in C++?

Tags: c++, programming-practices

Suppose that I have

- three classes `P`, `C1`, `C2`,
- composition (strong aggregation) relations between `P <>- C1` and `P <>- C2`, i.e. every instance of `P` contains an instance of `C1` and an instance of `C2`, which are destroyed when the parent `P` instance is destroyed.
- an association relation between instances of `C1` and `C2` (not necessarily between children of the same `P`).

To implement this, in C++ I normally

- define three classes `P`, `C1`, `C2`,
- define two member variables of `P` of type `boost::shared_ptr<C1>`, `boost::shared_ptr<C2>`, and initialize them with newly created objects in `P`'s constructor,
- implement the relation between `C1` and `C2` using a `boost::weak_ptr<C2>` member variable in `C1` and a `boost::weak_ptr<C1>` member variable in `C2` that can be set later via appropriate methods, when the relation is established.

Now, I also would like to have a link from each `C1` and `C2` object to its `P` parent object. What is a good way to implement this?

My current idea is to use a simple **constant** raw pointer (`P * const`) that is set from the constructor of `P` (which, in turn, calls the constructors of `C1` and `C2`), i.e. something like:

```
class C1
{
  public:
    C1(P * const p, ...)
    : paren(p)
    {
    ...
    }

  private:
    P * const parent;
    ...
};

class P
{
  public:
    P(...)
    : childC1(new C1(this, ...))
    ...
    {
        ...
    }

  private:
    boost::shared_ptr<C1> childC1;
    ...
};
```

Honestly I see no risk in using a **private constant** raw pointer in this way but I know that raw pointers are often frowned upon in C++ so I was wondering if there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers create headaches when you use them to manage dynamically allocated resources. In this case, however, a pointer is a simple "backlink" to the parent, and it cannot be changed during the lifetime of a child object (i.e. there's no re-parenting). This is a good solution that helps you keep things simple.

Comment: I had thought about using a weak pointer from child to parent, but in order to initialize it I need to give the child a shared pointer pointing to the parent. But the parent does not have a shared pointer to itself so I discarded this solution.

Comment: @Giorgio A weak pointer would probably be an overkill in this situation, because the parent fully owns its children. Since children get deleted along with the parent, there is little reason to give them weak pointers.

Comment: The fact that a weak pointer would be an overkill is not the only problem. To construct a boost::weak_ptr<P> I need to pass it a boost::shared_ptr<P>: how can I get this boost::shared_ptr<P> within the constructor of P?

Comment: This is the main thing enable_shared_from_this is good for:  it allows the parent to recover a shared_ptr from its this pointer within the constructor call.